# Why does bash go into an infinite loop?

Tags: linux, bash

I was trying out different ways of emulating a boolean variable in bash. One method is:

```
readonly T=1
readonly F=0
((T)) && echo "true" || echo "false"
((F)) && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

which prints **true** and **false** respectively. Then I had a brain cramp and typed:

```
! ((F)) && "yes"
```

expecting to see **yes** in the terminal. However, without the **echo** command, it went into an infinite loop printing **y**. Can someone explain what bash is doing here?

Comment: `yes` is the name of a program that prints `y` continuously.

Comment: He knows what it should be, he realized that he forgot `echo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` didn't go into an infinite loop. You're running the `yes` program, whose description is:

> `yes` - output a string repeatedly until killed

`y` is the default string that it prints. The purpose is to pipe it to a command that's going to ask lots of confirmation questions, so you can give the same answer to all of them. E.g.

```
yes | ./configure
```

Comment: To answer the exact question, regarding what `bash` is doing: `bash` is blocking, waiting for `yes` to complete.